# Filter a string based on a variable number of substrings in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell with a variable number of substrings separated by a comma.

**To search:**

- "first,second,third"
- "primero,segundo,tercero,cuarto"
- "eins,zwei"

and I have a column with many strings that are composed by some of the substrings:

**Column with full items**

- "first,second,third,fourth"
- "primero,segundo,tercero,cuarto,quinto"
- "primero,tercero,cuarto"
- "eins,zwei,drei"

...and so on...

I would like to find the items of the Column above which has the substrings to be searched. Not a big issue when the amount of substrings is fixed but when it varies it becomes harder. I have a horrible formula that counts the number of commas and then it uses IF for each amount of substrings to search and several `FIND(index(SPLIT(A4,","),2)` for each substring. The formula is gigant and hard to handle.

Can you think of a better way of doing it?

Here there is an example of what I would like to do. The blue cells are the ones that should have the formula.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pD9r4JF48cVSNGqA4D69lSyasWxTvAcOhWWu1xW2mgw/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you are trying to find? Are you looking for exact matches between column A and F? Are you looking for entries in column A where all substrings are contained in column F? Or is one substring enough? What is `a, b ,d`?

Comment: I'm looking for entries in column A where all substrings are contained in column F. a b and d is just an index for column F.

Comment: if a match is found whats your ideal output?

Comment: it would be the index of the column where it was found. like the a b c d in the example spreadsheet

Comment: It might be easier with a script.

Comment: I've never used a script. It sounds interesting that it would run the computation on the server-side (I have a very large spreadsheet) so that could make the sheet faster

Comment: If you are interested in learning start with the [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), study the methods for [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet), as well as basic Javascript features like [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [if statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp). The point is theat you can dynamically iterate through all susbtrings without knowing how many there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help! In the end, I used the QUERY function.

`=QUERY(E:F,"select E where F contains '" & textjoin("' AND F contains '",TRUE,split(A2,",")) &"'" )`

If you are interested, you can see the solution applied in the original spreadsheet :)